# Can a Ph.D student change his adviser, if he is supported by a Research Assistantship by the adviser upon admission (and possibly first year)?

Tags: phd, advisor, research-assistantship

According to my offer, I am admitted to the Ph.D program and funded by a Research Assistantship by Professor X. Nevertheless, I am interested in other research directions, and we are supposed to decide our adviser by the end of the first semester.

Is it appropriate to change adviser in my case, as I am funded by Professor X?

Comment: What country? What field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is usually possible, but plan for two things to happen:

- *[Almost certain]* You will lose this RA-stipend. RAs are usually in the context of specific projects and under the supervision of specific advisors, so when you decide to work on an entirely different project with a different position (which is typically your right as a PhD student) you become ineligible to be funded in this way. You need to understand that most RAs come from projects, where a PI has promised to a funding agency or company that a certain project will be delivered within a time frame. If you then decide to work on something else, the PI needs to find another person to actually do the work that has been promised. Note that this does not necessarily mean that you won't have a stipend anymore, but it will likely need to be a different source (e.g., either a TA position or an RA sponsored 
  by your new advisor).
- *[Possible]* There may be some fallout with the PI sponsoring the RA. I guess most people can accept that sometimes the first year shows that you are not an ideal fit and switching advisors is the best solution for everybody, but planning to switch all along when accepting the offer may understandably lead to some bad blood. In essence, you are trying to milk a year of funding out of a project you have no intention of actually contributing to long-term. Many people will find this highly disagreeable.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed response! I also asked some of my other friends, who told me that while I am working on this project based on Research Assistantship, my thesis does not necessarily have to be the same project. So, this actually helps me a lot as I would definitely like to gain experience in research while having an open opportunity for choosing a research interest that is more aligned with mine.

Comment: _you become ineligible to be funded in this way_ — **...from the same grant.**  Of course your new advisor is free to offer you a research assistantship from their grants instead.

Answer (score -1):

By rights, you can (in most universities).

However, it will be super-awkward.

It seems like you did not enter the program through a scholarship but with a job (RA-ship) to fund your studies. This is an academic way of saying, "I give you a job. I also admit you in the program."

Therefore, you are free to choose any supervisor but you need to keep your job as your source of income (you eat, wear-cloths and sleep under roof, right?). Your current supervisor is your reporting officer for your job.

Best is to have an open-talk with your current supervisor. Usually, they are understanding and (though hard to believe) supportive.

Comment: How come this got minus-ed off? I am answering the best as I can.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! It helped me a lot. It was not me who downvoted it; instead, I upvoted it, but due to my limited reputation, it is not shown in public unfortunately.

Comment: @NeverBe ... don't worry. All the best.

Comment: _I give you a job. I also admit you in the program._ — In sane departments, at least in the US, the _department_ admits you to the program, not the PI. — _(though hard to believe)_ — Why is it hard to believe??